# C for loop optimisation by embedding statements into loop-head itself

Tags: c

Just wondering if these variations of for loops are more efficient and practical.
By messing with the c for loop syntax i can embedd statements that would go in the loop-body into the loop-head like so:

Example 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // Simple program that prints out the command line arguments passed in
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        for(int i = 1; puts(argv[i++]), i < argc;);

        // This does the same as this:
        // for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        // {
        //  puts(argv[i]);
        // }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I understand how the commas work in the for loop it goes through each statement in order, evaluates them then disregards all but the last one which is why it is able to iterate using the "i < argc"condition. There is no need for the final segment to increment the i variable as i did that in the middle segment of the loop head (in the puts(argv[i++]) bit).
Is this more efficient or is just just cleaner to seperate it into the loop body rather than combine it all into one line?

Example 2:

```
int stringLength(const char * string)
{
    // Function that counts characters up until null terminator character and returns the total
    int counter = 0;
    for(counter; string[counter] != '\0'; counter++);
    return counter;
    // Same as:
    //int counter = 0;
    // for(int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
    //{
    //  counter++;
    //}
    //return counter;
}
```

This one seems more efficient than the version with the loop body as no local variable for the for-loop is initialised. Is it conventional to do these sorts of loops with no bodies?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing efficient about putting the body there. Nothing. You should try to compare generated binary code or at least runtime. This way is not efficient and less readable.

Comment: O(N) algorihtmns cannot be *optimised*. Period.

Comment: @wildplasser: Baloney.

Comment: @wildplasser, there are constant time algorithms, so it is totally possible to optimize a linear algorithm and reduce it to constant time. Not to mention, there are cases were you prefer one linear algorithm over another because of a lower coefficient.

Comment: Apart from *performance*, puts(NULL) is garbage.

Comment: Try putting the alternatives into [the Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org)  and seeing whether different code is generated [after testing the code actually produces the expected output].\

Comment: You can use tbis style to punish the developer who will have to test and debug the code.  If revenge/torture etc is not your wish, keep it simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: Correctness

Make sure code is correct.

Consider OP's code below. Does it attempt to print `argv[argc]` which would be bad?

```
if (argc > 1) {
    for(int i = 1; puts(argv[i++]), i < argc;);
```

I initially thought it did.  So did another user.  Yet it OK.
… and this is exactly why code is weak.

Code not only should *be* correct, better code *looks* correct too.  Using an anti-pattern as suggested by OP is rarely<sup>1</sup> as good thing.

---

Step 2: Since code variations have the same [big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), focus on *understandably*.

Sculpt your code – remove what is not needed.

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
  puts(argv[i]);
}
```

What OP is doing is a trivial optimization concern.
[Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/94903)

---

> Is it conventional to do these sorts of loops with no bodies?

Not really.

The key to the *style* of coding is to follow your group's style guide.  Great software is often a team effort.  If your group's likes to minimize bodies, go ahead. I have seen the opposite more common, explicit `{ some_code }` bodies.

---

Note: `int stringLength(const char * string)` fails for strings longer than `INT_MAX`.  Better to use `size_t` as the return type – thus an example of step 1 faltering.

---

<sup>1</sup> All coding style rules, except this rule, have exceptions.

Comment: Readability is probably much better over making miniscule "optimisations" like these i think. The compiler probably will deal with these optimisations anyways ill have to look into the assembly generated to see if there really is a difference. Thats a good point that it will still have the same big O.

Comment: Optimization by obscuration isn't optimization... (it's a stupid pet-trick applied to code) Dump to assembly and compare. Unless there is a significant and meaningful savings using the anti-pattern, don't do it.